# Filter QTableWidget using logic expression from string

Tags: python, pyqt5, filtering

I am trying to filter a QTableWidget using a string provided by the user. The String is from a Textbox. In the end, only rows that match the expression should be visible.

In the textbox you should be able to type things like:

```
'item1' or 'item2'
```

(Displays all rows containing item1 or item2)

or

```
'item1' and 'item2'
```

(Displays all rows containing item1 and item2)

It should also be possible with more than two items and both, "and" and "or" in one statement.

```
    def applyFilter(self):
        try:
            for row in range(1, len(self.log)):
                print('\nRow Content: ',row, self.log[row])
                if eval(self.filterTextbox.text()) in self.log[row]: #if the logic expression in the textbox is in current row
                    print('Filter keyword is in this Row')
                    self.tableWidget.showRow(row-1)
                else:
                    print('Filter keyword is not in this Row')
                    self.tableWidget.hideRow(row-1)
        except SyntaxError: #textbox is empty (All rows should be visible)
            self.showAllRows(self.log)
```

The for-loop goes through all rows in the Table. self.log is a list that contains a list of items for every row.

The code iterates through all rows and checks if the logic statement from the textbox applies to the row.

eval() takes a String and converts it to executable python code.

This code doesn't work, I think the problem lies in the "if" statement. The code works with only one argument, but as soon as I start using "and" and "or", the table doesn't get filtered correctly.

Comment: Your underlying problem has nothing to do with PyQt but you need to implement a parser of a Boolean expression, so I recommend you rewrite your question focusing on it.

Comment: As soon as you add `and/or`, you turn it into a boolean expression. So it can only ever return `True/False`. You should probably be using regexps to search for the strings, rather than logical statements. (Or convert the statements into regexps). Note that [QTableWidget.findItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#findItems) can search using [regexps, wildcards, and so forth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum).

Comment: @ekhumoro I dont think that I can achieve what I want to using regexps, because I can only match Strings with "or". I want to be able to match a row that has at least two set statements. I cant match a row that has "term1" and "term2". I can only match one of them using term1|term2.

Comment: My suggestion was to convert the statements into regexps (plural). So the *string-matching* is done by regexps, which are then connected together using logical operators. (Of course, if you really only ever intend to do *exact, case-sensitive* matching, regexps aren't needed). As pointed out previously, you will have to parse/convert the input into expressions and operators first. The operations must then be performed in code (not `eval`). (On reflection, `findItems` isn't going to be much help here, because it just isn't flexible enough).